# What is the difference between fixed precision and variable precision?

Tags: sql-server

I am kind of a datatype noob. I was looking at the differences in all the number datatypes in SQL server and I saw one answer saying:

> Decimal has a fixed precision while float has variable precision

I know that Precision is the number of digits in a number. Specifically I do not know what is the difference between fixed precision and variable precision.

Comment: This isn't a SQL question, it's a general computing question. I recommend you just search the interweb for the information. SO isn't the place to try to fit a tutorial into an answer. Maybe start with Wikipedia? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: Fixed vs variable (not-fixed). Reading through this would also likely help, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that Precision is the number of digits in a number.

In this context there are two types of precision: Fixed and Variable

Fixed:

> The number of digits in any particular number is the same.

Variable:

> The number of digits in any number can vary from number to number.

This statement...

> Decimal has a fixed precision while float has variable precision

Where Decimal can hold a fixed value, variable precision most likely in this context implies how variable-length significands (and sometimes exponents) are sized depending on actual "need" of calculation that will be done with that particular number. This is perhaps related to arbitrary-precision floating-point arithmetic.

Not to mention the significance of how floating point numbers are stored in terms of mantissa bits, and how they are usually not precise in the context of a calculation result being so precise that you could define it as 100% accurate (for instance, PI).

That's my best explanation, but I will agree that the wording of that quote can be a tad vague. Perhaps more context would be sufficient to properly answer this.

**EDIT:** Some of the commentators make good points. Here are some helpful links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Best of luck to you mate.